# Error when can't mouse move in body using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying this [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fxk52/2/)

In HTML:

```
...
    <body>
       <div id="button-wrapper" style="position: absolute; opacity: 1; width: 27px; height: 20px;">
          <input type="submit" value="submit">
       </div>
    </body> 
...
```

In jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#button-wrapper").parent().mousemove(function(e) {
       jQuery("#button-wrapper").css({
           top : e.pageY - 10,
           left : e.pageX + 30
       });
   });
});
```

An error occurs when I move the mouse on body. The submit button can't run on mouse move event. How should I fix this?

Comment: I don't even understand WHAT this question is asking O.o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('mousemove',function(e) {
        $("#button-wrapper").css({
            top : e.pageY - 10,
            left : e.pageX + 30
        });
    });
});
```

You should first use all `$(document)` since you are trying selecting `parent()` of your div which is `body` which can be easily `the document` itself. Then use `on()` for live DOM interpretation.

Then translate this `jQuery("#button-wrapper")` to `$("#button-wrapper")` just because if you use one, don't use the other.

Also translate `$(document).ready(function(){});` part  into `$(function(){});`.

Comment: .on() will only be live if you specify a selector as the second argument.

Comment: I'm not saying it won't work (as it clearly does), only that it isn't using a .live()-like event listener, as per: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: oh sorry, maybe i misunderstood cause of my bad english, but live() is not deprecated? @Selosindis

Comment: Not a problem, just adding some clarification. :)  .live() is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. http://api.jquery.com/live/